# How do I sections of a text body in specific areas

Tags: color, text, inkscape

I am new to Inkscape and currently struggling with coloring text.  I have a main body of text, small size 4pt, and I wish to block color in certain areas of it.

For example imagine an A4 white sheet full of black text.  Then draw a solid red circle in the middle of that area.  I wish the text passing through that circle to become red-take on that color (leaving white background).

Any ideas how I can do this in Inkscape?

Comment: Welcome on GD, Mark. Can you tell us something about your efforts? e.g. have you tried to [convert the text to path](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/advanced/tutorial-advanced.en.html) and select the letters to be filled? Or have you tried to use some [clip or mask](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clip.html) filter? Please, try!

Answer (score 1):

1. Make your text, select it and duplicate it (Ctrl+D). The duplicate appears exactly on top of the original.
   [image: step 1: make text and duplicate it]
2. Change fill color of the duplicate to red (just leftclick on the red color in the palette below)
   [image: step 2: change color of duplicate]
3. Draw your circle on top.
   [image: step 3: draw circle]
4. Change back to selection tool (F1), shift+leftclick the red text object (result: both circle and red text object selected). Then go to Object menu > Clip > Set.
   [image]
5. Done. The part of the red text which is outside of the circle has now been clipped, and the circle itself "disappeared" (only used as clipping path). If necessary, you can change the clipping path without undoing the clipping.
   [image]

More information on clipping in [Tavmjong's excellent Inkscape manual](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clip-Clipping.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. Write the text in black.
2. Convert the glyphs to path.
3. Mark every glyph*, choose path:unite. Duplicate.
4. Draw a circle.
5. Mark cirlcle and one layer of glyphs, select Path:Overlapping.
6. Colorize the overlapped part of glyphs.

If you know a way to mark all/a block of glyphs in a simple step, please explain how in the comments. :)